# Best way to stage file from cloud storage to windows machine

Tags: windows-xp, quickbooks

I am wanting to store a data file for Quickbooks in the cloud.  I understand that the data file is more of a database-in-a-file, so I know that I don't want to simply have the data file itself in a cloud directory.

When I say 'cloud', I'm meaning something like Google Drive or box.com.

What I see working is that I want to write a script (bat file, or do they have something new and improved for Windows XP, like some .net nonsense or something?)

The script would:

1) Download the latest copy of the data file from cloud storage and put it in a directory on the local machine

2) Launch Quickbooks with that data file

3) When the user exits Quickbooks, copy the data file back up into the cloud storage.

4) Rejoice.

So, my question(s)...  Is there something that already does this?  Is there an easily scriptable interface to work with the cloud storage options?  In my ideal world, I'd be able to say 'scp google-drive://blah/blah.dat localdir' and have it copy the file down, and do the opposite after running QB.  I'm guessing I'm not going to get that.

Comment: My latest plan that I've put into place..  I have downloaded the 'Google Drive' program which causes the cloud drive to look like a regular directory.  I've got the bat file set up to pull down a tarball from the cloud directory and uncompress it for quickbooks.  Then #2 happens and for #3, it tarballs up the 'Company Files' directory and puts it back into the cloud directory.    Now I'm working on using actual Drive SDK methods to get and put the tarball.  Waiting for the Drive app to sync on its own is unpredicatable.

Answer (score 0):

Intuit already provides a product to do this. It is called Intuit Data Protect and it backs up your Quickbooks company file to the cloud for you.

http://appcenter.intuit.com/intuitdataprotect

regards,
Jarred

Comment: Jarred,  Thanks for that comment.  I'm looking for a better solution that won't incur a monthly fee.